# Prevent navigating twice when clicking a button quickly

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and would like to prevent navigating to the same screen twice when the user tap/click a button quickly. Here is my reducer:

```
export const navReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    let nextState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case TO_LOGIN:
            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
                        type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
                        routeName: TO_LOGIN
                    })],
                    key: null
                }), state);
            break;

        case TO_HOME:
            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
                        type: NavigationActions.NAVIGATE,
                        routeName: TO_HOME
                    })],
                }), state);
            break;

        default:
            if (action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE) {
                console.log('action: ' + JSON.stringify(action));
                console.log('state: ' + JSON.stringify(state));
                console.log('nextState: ' + JSON.stringify(RootNav.router.getStateForAction(action, state)));
            }

            nextState = RootNav.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
            break;
    }

    return nextState || state;
};
```

The output of the console.logs is:

First click:

```
action: {"type":"Navigation/NAVIGATE","routeName":"ClinicDetail","params":{"section":0,"from":"near"}}
state: {"index":0,"routes":[{"routeName":"TO_HOME","key":"id-1496294907150-4"}]}
nextState: {"index":0,"routes":[{"routeName":"TO_HOME","key":"id-1496294907150-4"}]}
```

Second click:

```
action: {"type":"Navigation/NAVIGATE","routeName":"ClinicDetail","params":{"section":0,"from":"near"}}
state: {"index":0,"routes":[{"routeName":"TO_HOME","key":"id-1496294907150-4"}]}
nextState: {"index":0,"routes":[{"routeName":"TO_HOME","key":"id-1496294907150-4"}]}
```

What kind of check to do so I can prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/271#issuecomment-290449534) you can add a `navigateWithDebounce` in the `addNavigationHelpers` and dispatch this instead of `navigate`:

```
_addNavigationHelpers = (navigation) => {
    const original = addNavigationHelpers(navigation);
    let debounce;
    return {
        ...original,
        navigateWithDebounce: (routeName, params, action) => {
            let func = () => {
                if (debounce) {
                    return;
                }

                navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName,
                    params,
                    action
                }));

                debounce = setTimeout(() => {
                    debounce = 0;
                }, 1000)
            };
            return func();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is already supported by react navigation. You can simply add **key** param:

> this.props.navigation.navigate({ key: 'ClinicDetail', routeName:
>   'ClinicDetail', params: {...}})

See [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/271#issuecomment-362726430)

Answer (score 0):

This works but only if you're using addNavigationHelpers. If not, also based on Github comment ([Here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/271#issuecomment-295581754)) you can override the method:

```
NavigationActions.overridedNavigate = (routeName, params, action) => {
    // some override logic
    return NavigationActions.navigate(routeName, params, action)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by creating a module which calls a function only once in the passed interval.

Example: If you wish to navigate from Home -> About
And you press the About button twice in say `400 ms`.

```
navigateToAbout = () => dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'About'}))

const pressHandler = callOnce(navigateToAbout,400);
<TouchableOpacity onPress={pressHandler}>
 ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The module will take care that it calls navigateToAbout `only once` in 400 ms.

Here is the link to the NPM module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/call-once-in-interval