# React native debounce hook without external dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on a debounce hook, I can wrap all of my 'OnPress' functions with. I would like not to use any external libraries (or only use an external library if it is very small).

My example is based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44300840). And there is also [an approach](https://github.com/rgabs/call-once-in-interval/blob/master/index.js) that seems a bit simpler. In both approaches I don't see them clear the timer when the component dismounts.

I have created the following and it seems to work. I'm going to use it a lot of places, so I would like some validation on my approach. Is this an OK way to do it? Will I get a performance hit by this approach?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

/**
 * After calling an action, delay the next call by debounceTimeout.
 * Use this function if you do not want an action to be called many times in a row. Use the debounceTimeout to reset,
 * and make the action ready to be called again. A typical scenario is to avoid overfloading an api with many calls or
 * prevent a navigation library from pushing many navigation stacks; if a user presses the navigation button mulitple times in a row
 * @param action A function that should be debounced. E.g an OnClick action for a touchable component
 * @param debounceTimeout A timeout for the debounce
 * @returns The action wrapped in a debounce function
 *
 **/
const useDebounceAction = (
    action: () => void,
    debounceTimeout = 600
): (() => void) => {
    let debounceHandler: NodeJS.Timeout;
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    // useEffect to clean up our debounceHandler when component (using this hook) gets unmonted
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            clearTimeout(debounceHandler);
        };
    }, [action]);
    const debounceWrappedAction = () => {
        if (isLoading) {
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        action();
        debounceHandler = setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, debounceTimeout);
    };
    return debounceWrappedAction;
};

export default useDebounceAction;
```

Example of how I would use it:

```
// 'createNewTaskApi' could be a function that creates a new task on the api for each call
// Could also be a redux action
import { createNewTaskApi } from './src/apiCalls';
import useDebounceAction from './src/common/hooks/useDebounceAction';
import Button from './src/common/Button';

const CreateNewTaskButton = ({ task } : { task: Task }) => {
 // We do not want a fast doubble tab on our button to create two tasks.
 // Therefore we wrap createNewTaskApi in our useDebounceClickHandler
 const debounceOnPress = useDebounceAction(() => createNewTaskApi(task), 300);
 return <Button title="Create Task" onPress={debounceOnPress} />
}
```

EDIT 1: After testing I have somes issues, if i call my useEffect with empty array to avoid trigger extra re-renders, i will get an error with update react state on unmounted component

```
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(debounceHandler);
        };
    }, []);
```

EDIT 2: The useCallback function solved my issue in `EDIT 1`

EDIT 3: The use callback function memoized the context. So i will always get the initialized context when pressing button. To solve this i  added the `[action]`. So if the action changes, a new function will be created. But now I'm back at the updating state on unmounted component errors

```
 const debounceWrappedAction = useCallback(() => {
        if (isLoading) {
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        action();
        debounceHandler = setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, debounceTimeout);
    }, [action]);
```

EDIT 4: I also added the [action] to the useEffect call. I think that solved my issue with updating state on unmounted component errors again. I think that the `clearTimeout(debounceHandler);` sometimes referred to an old debounceHandler.

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(debounceHandler);
        };
    }, [action]);
```

EDIT 5: Removed the useCallback function again. Because while i didn't got any update state errors, my debounce didn't work either